# What's the relationship between equals and hashCode?

Tags: java, equals, hashcode

Question: if there are two objects o1 and o2 such that o1.equals(o2), what is java's standard convention about the relationship between o1.hashCode() == o2.hashCode()?

Answer: o1.hashCode() == o2.hashCode()

I don't know why..what i thought was since o1 and o2 are different objects, they shouldn't have the same hashCode. If what the question says were o1 == o2, then I would say they have the same hashCode since both o1 and o2 point to the same object.

Can anyone point out what I did wrong?

Comment: Have you read the documentation? http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#hashCode--

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Equals and Hashcode always go hand in hand. If `o1 == o2`, then they point to the same memory and hashcodes are trivially equal. However, one you implement Equals, you always have to make sure that when Equals returns true, Hashcode must return the same value.

Here are the [official docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#hashCode%28%29) which set out the requirements/standards.

Comment: So say that if I construct two objects of the same class with the same numerical fields, but as long as I don't point out that they .equals(), I can't say they have the same hashCode?

Comment: @user3579298 the general contract is that if `a.equals(b)` is true, then `a.hashCode() == b.hashCode()`. Note that this does *not* mean that if `a.equals(b)` is false, `a.hashCode() != b.hashCode()`

Comment: If they are not `.equals()`, they may or may not have the same hash code. But if they are `.equals()`, they MUST have the same hash code.

Comment: That make sense to me, I'll just try to remember this rule, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

.equals is used to evaluate the value of an object. When objects are hashed, their numerical values on a systems level are used to produce a hash code (an integer, if you will). If the objects are the exact same (e.g. in terms of attributes), they will have the same numerical sequence and therefore hash to the same value.